# How to assign a keyboard shortcut to just the Command key on Mac OS

Tags: macos, keyboard, launchpad

Coming from linux (KDE) I was able to [assign a keyboard shortcut to the meta key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246886/how-do-i-open-the-application-launcher-on-kde-with-just-the-meta-windows-key). I'm wondering if it's possible to do something similar with the Command key on macOS? I would like to open launchpad after a single press of the Command key ideally.

Comment: So, how would you use it for other shortcuts, like Copy and Paste? The OS acts on a keypress when the button is down, not on release. Probably easier to assign an F key to Launchpad.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) using [Complex Modifications](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/manual/configuration/configure-complex-modifications/).

There is no such modification in the [Karabiner-Elements complex_modifications rules list](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/) so you will have to add it manually:

0. Install and setup Karabiner-Elements.
1. Open `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json`.
2. Add the following rule in `profiles.complex_modifications.rules` list:

```
{
    "description": "Open Launchpad if left_command is pressed alone.",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "left_command",
                "modifiers": {
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "left_command"
                }
            ],
            "to_if_alone": [
                {
                    "shell_command": "open -a Launchpad.app"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Save the changes. The rule should appear in Karabiner-Elements UI as shown in the picture below:
   [image: Karabiner-Elements rule]