# Bind to key release, not key press

Tags: macos, keyboard

On macOS, is there a way to have releasing Cmd (just that one key) say open Spotlight? Similar to tapping the Super key on Gnome in Linux.

On Linux, key release triggers bindings, so its no problem to bind to a modifier key like the Super key or Command key. I believe macOS binds to key presses, so this may not be possible. Unless someone has a way around that?

Comment: The shortcut is `Cmd-Space` to launch Spotlight.   The problem with binding to a single key, especially to just the press or release, is that humans are imperfect and this will trigger all sorts of unwanted behaviors.

Comment: Works just fine for everyone on Linux / Gnome. Its the default even.

Comment: It’s not a “Linux” thing, it’s dependent on the keyboard driver and whether or not you can [access the raw keyboard scan codes](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1080). You can do this on macOS - I have an app called ControllerMate that will listen for these scan codes.  **It’s not native to Finder** (notice, I didn’t say macOS).  Finder is designed for a consistent user experience and binding a release key state to a commonly used modifier  keys is bound to cause issues.

Comment: Do you want single Cmd press to open Spotlight but Cmd+Key to act as usual? If so, it's possible with Karabiner-Elements. See my answer on a similar question https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/453785/484998

Answer (score 1):

> On Linux, key release triggers bindings, so its no problem to bind to a modifier key like the Super key or Command key.

#### Keypress are ALREADY bound to KeyRelease

There’s a free utility called `xev` that, unfortunately can only be run in XQuartz (when I find a native app, I’ll test and post that).  When running this utility, it will report the scan codes that are generated from each key press.

From a previous answer I wrote entitled [How do I get the calculator button on a Microsoft Sculpt keyboard working?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/317556/119271), we can see that the command (not specifically <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>) is bound to the *release* state of the key.

> On macOS, is there a way to have releasing Cmd (just that one key) say open Spotlight? Similar to tapping the Super key on Gnome in Linux.

I also don’t recommend binding UI functions (i.e. Spotlight) to a single modifier.  I’m not a Linux user (prefer FreeBSD) but I am familiar with it.  The “super key” is a Linux convention and is usually mapped to the *unused* <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> on a PC keyboard or the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> on a Mac (booted to Linux).

**As macOS already has this key assigned, mapping additional functionality to it’s individual pressed state,  can only cause problems.**

Answer (score -3):

### Sticky Keys

I think the feature you're looking for is called *Sticky Keys*.

From [Change Keyboard settings for accessibility on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlae61a6de/mac#:%7E:text=Press%20the%20Shift%20key%20five,Sticky%20Keys%20on%20or%20off.):

> Press a set of modifier keys one at a time in sequence instead of all at once. For example, enter the key combination Option-Command-F5 by pressing each key in sequence.

By default, Sticky Keys can be enabled by pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key five times. You can modify this as well as other parameters by clicking on the info button [image].

Note : You can also enable Sticky Keys by going to *System Settings > Accessibility > Keyboard* and enabling *Sticky Keys*.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related at all to the question. Sticky keys is for when you have multiple modifiers and want to press them sequentially instead of together. The question is about using a single modifier by itself to trigger an action immediately.

Comment: @Barmar Oh? I think I've misunderstood the question then...